# rich:modalPanel closes without Validation

Tags: richfaces

I am trying to validate a data in inside a rich:modalPanel; The behavior i see is quite strange.

I have a dropdown and a Add button to that dropdown, for the first time when i try to add data to the dropdown by clicking the Add button the validations are successful, how oever when once the user adds the data for the first time and tries to enter a new data second time by opening newAddUserDialog; and now when the validation fails, the modal panel simply hides. Even if I remove the code for hiding the modal panel (onComplete event inside a4j:commadButton), the window simply closes on click of the buttion.

```
        <rich:modalPanel id="newAddUserDialog" autosized="true">

    <a4j:outputPanel id="addName_panel"
        styleClass="largePanel">

        <a4j:form>

            <rich:messages layout="list" showDetail="false"
                errorClass="validationError" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="100%">

                <h:outputLabel value="Name:" styleClass="label" />
                <h:inputText id="nameId"
                    value="#{formBean.name}" maxlength="32"
                    required="true" styleClass="width100">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="32" />
                </h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="100%">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <a4j:commandButton id="addBtn" value="Add"
                        styleClass="stdButton" action="doAddUserName"
                        reRender="addName_panel, targetsMaster">

                        <rich:componentControl for="newAddUserDialog"
                            event="oncomplete"
                            operation="#{(!modelValidationMessages.hasMessages and empty facesContext.maximumSeverity) ? 'hide' : 'focus'}" />
                    </a4j:commandButton>

                    <a4j:commandButton id="addUser_cancel" value="Cancel"
                        styleClass="stdButton">
                        <rich:componentControl for="newAddUserDialog" event="onclick"
                            operation="hide" />
                    </a4j:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </a4j:form>

    </a4j:outputPanel>

</rich:modalPanel>
```

What could be the reason for such behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is the problem addressed by the Richfaces team.  Please [check this out](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ModalPanelValidation)